# Store element's data as html attribute

Tags: html, stateful

I already saw some tools which stores some state or data inside element's attribute:

```
<div clicks="2" id="myDiv" class="some-class">
```

but it's invalid in some doctypes.

At all. Is this a good solution for stateful elements?
If not, some advice will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412645/whats-the-best-html-attribute-to-use-to-store-information-for-jquery-to-parse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under HTML5 you have the option to use, valid, `data-*` attributes, such as, in this case `data-clicks` to store user-defined data.

References:

- [`Embedding custom non-visible data with the data attributes`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).
- [HTML5 Custom Data Attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/).