# What is the proper place to put AJAX-related content in a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

When you need a link to contain info for an AJAX call what is the proper place to put the info?

I've always put it in the [rel attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#adef-rel), but reading the documentation for rel it seems this isn't the proper place:

> This attribute describes the
>   relationship from the current document
>   to the anchor specified by the href
>   attribute. The value of this attribute
>   is a space-separated list of link
>   types.

You could parse the href and pull out the info you need:

```
<a class="store_link" href="/store/4/name-of-store">Name of Store</a>

$(".store_link").click( function() {
    id = $(this).attr('href').split('/')[2];
});
```

But links won't always have hrefs

Is there a proper place to put this information?

Comment: Could you give us an example of the content you're trying to store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use non-standard HTML attributes, prefixed with `data-` See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209428/non-standard-attributes-on-html-tags-good-thing-bad-thing-your-thoughts/209432#209432) for more details. It won't validate, but it works perfectly. You need to decide how important 100% validation is to you.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery allows you to store data against DOM objects in a much more elegant way.

See the `data()` api here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Another way that is used often but can make your X/HTML non compliant is creating your own attributes.

eg. `<div id="myDiv" someattr="lipsum dolor sit emet"> ... </div>`

and then in your jQuery you can get the value by doing `$('myDiv').attr('someattr')`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)