# Get an input's "checked" state

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, input

I have this basic HTML structure:

```
<fieldset>
    <input/>
    <label></label>
    <div class="toggle_box">
        <div class="switch"></div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I would like this to happen when my input is checked:

```
<fieldset>
    <input checked="checked" />
    <label></label>
    <div class="toggle_box">
        <div class="switch" state="on"></div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Add state="on" to the switch div. Is there any selector in jquery I can use to get the checked state of that particular input? (there are multiple on a page).

Thanks for your brainstorming!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This works](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/WMSWk/); you'll need to add `type="checkbox"` to your inputs to make them checkboxes.  (Observe the effect by inspecting the `switch` `div`s with Chrome's Dev Tools or Firebug.)

```
$('fieldset input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    var el=$(this).parent().find('.switch');
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) el.attr('state','on');
    else el.removeAttr('state');
});
```

Comment: @josh this should work too right: $('fieldset input[type=checkbox]:checked').parent().find('.switch').attr('state','on') ;
???

Comment: @josh, just to know, can we use attribute 'state' for DIV tag? or we can use any like "foo", "bar", ..

Comment: @SnippetSpace: Depends on what you're doing.  That will only add `state="on"` to `div`s associated with checked inputs *when that line of code is executed*.  If you're doing this from something like a submit function, you're fine.  Above, I register an event handler (via `change()`) so that the `state` attribute is dynamically updated when the user checks or unchecks a checkbox.

Comment: @josh, if it is like that, can we store value by adding attribute to an element instead of storing value in an input[type='text'] box

Comment: @Hoque: You can add anything as an attribute to any tag.  However, strictly speaking, adding a `state` attribute to a `div` is invalid from a HTML DTD standpoint -- the [`div` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) has only the standard [global attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#global-attributes).  However, adding custom attributes (aka *expando attributes*) doesn't break anything in any browser, so there's really no harm.  More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209428/) and [here](http://bit.ly/jUgJeH).

Comment: @Hoque: If you have arbitrary data you'd like to store associated with a DOM element, it is a better idea (and more performant) to store that data using jQuery's [`data()` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Data).  In short: When using `data()`, your data is stored in a JavaScript variable (which means you can store complex objects); when using `attr()`, your data is stored as text in the DOM.  [Here's a good article with more information.](http://apheliondynamics.com/blog/2010/01/19/the-power-of-jquery-data-and-a-practical-example/)

Answer (score 1):

You can put all these divs inside another div, and then get the father div with*document.getElementById*, find the div you want in the content and change him.

```
<div id="fatherOfTheDivs">
        <fieldset>
            <input/>
            <label></label>
            <div class="toggle_box">
                <div id="div1" class="switch"></div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <input/>
            <label></label>
            <div id="div2" class="toggle_box">
                <div class="switch"></div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will accomplish it for you.

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().children('div.toggle_box').children('div.switch').attr('state', 'on');
    } else {
        $(this).parent().children('div.toggle_box').children('div.switch').removeAttr('state');
    }
});
```

You'll also have to modify your `<input />` to `<input type="checkbox" />`