# Is having "value" attribute to act as a hidden value a correct practice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As far as I know, `value` is being used as HTML input attribute.

```
<form action="form_action.asp" method="get">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit form" />
</form>
```

However, I was wondering, is it a correct practice, that I can use it in other HTML attributes, to act as  hidden value?

For example, for each table row, I would like to tag it with a unique ID, as the unique ID in SQL database. However, at the same time, I would also like to hide the unique ID from end users.

Here is the technique I have been using.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
XXX
</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.delete-button').click(function() {
        var clicked = $(this);
        alert(clicked.parent('tr').attr('value'));
    });    
 });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<table style="border-style:none">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Server Name</th>
            <th>IP Address</th>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-style:none" value="ROW ID 1">
            <td class="edit">Yahoo Server</td>
            <td class="edit">196.168.0.1</td>
            <td class = "delete-button" style="border-style:none"><a href="">DELETE</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-style:none" value="ROW ID 2">     
            <td class="edit">Google Server</td>
            <td class="edit">196.168.0.2</td>
            <td class = "delete-button" style="border-style:none"><a href="">DELETE</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Since I didn't do HTML and JavaScript quite often, I was wondering, whether the above is a correct and common used technique?

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209428/non-standard-attributes-on-html-tags-good-thing-bad-thing-your-thoughts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With strict HTML4/XHTML, you should not create arbitrary attributes on tags.  You can, but it is invalid for the schema.

With HTML5, the best practice is to use [`data-` attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/).

eg.

```
<tr style="border-style:none" data-rowid="ROW ID 1">
    <td class="edit">Yahoo Server</td>
    <td class="edit">196.168.0.1</td>
    <td class="delete-button" style="border-style:none"><a href="">DELETE</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: To add to this... nothing wrong with using data- attributes to store data, that's what they are for. But you have to realize that you can't trust the information you are sending. You said you are putting database unique IDs on there... if someone does an edit of them, what if they manipulated the ID? You need to make sure you handle that appropriately, like make sure they have the permission to do that, or what-have-you. They might send you any ID at all.

Comment: All good advice — data should not be bound to presentation. It is convenient to do it on a small scale, but it should be avoided.

Comment: @InfinitiesLoop is quite right, always check any data that is used within the browser, particularly if being sent back in some capacity - as nothing within the browser is safe from manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using values, I'd recommend to use attributes. JQuery supports attributes and it's a pretty common practice. 
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

On initialization you can set all the attributes, then you can have your own custom attribute to read the values you previous set (which can then map to a dictionary or something along those lines).

Does that help?

Comment: `value` **is** an attribute. It's the attribute named "value"

Answer (score 0):

No. In this case value is a form component.
You would just use id="ROW ID 2" or whatever your value is -

```
alert(clicked.parent('tr').attr('id'));
```

Also, this html is pretty archaic. Just my opinion and not to be taken as a snide remark, but a good review of html5 and css3 would be beneficial.

Comment: Opinion, as stated. The use of tabled html with or without css has been dissipating. Of course it does depend on the scenario. In some cases a data matrix is easier to display with tables, but not necessary. I say this just because the firm I work for holds it as a standard to never write html below current standards unless necessary - like newsletters that must be in html4 transitional. Most clients even write it in the proposal outlines that the html follow the latest, highest standard, which today is pointing to html5, but not necessarily saying that all code is awful if it is not html5.

Comment: I'm not one to give a damn about what people choose to do with their code, per say. My motto was always - if it works, then who cares how it was made. BUT - from a "professional" perspective - another term I try to throw away - tabled html is just going to piss the next programmer off and it can mean redoing the whole site if the client notices and calls you on it. Happened to an intern here while we were at Google I/O. Cost us about 10k in man hours to correct.

Comment: @Orbling - I would assume that very thing about someone that made the comment I made, but it's not like I fight for "DIVs" just to argue. Or that I care to argue at all. It's merely stating that "DIV" markup - or whatever one wants to call it - was created for a reason and that it has progressed very well, with tremendous support, and is unarguably much easier to work with for everyone.

Comment: @Kai Qing: Tables are correct usage for tabular data, they always have been, still are - even in the latest HTML specifications.  The problem was in the distant past people used them for layout purposes for non-tabular data, this is better achieved with DIV/CSS layout.  For tabular data, tables are arguably much easier to work with.  You are entitled to your opinions of course, but "if it works, who cares how it was made" is not a common "professional" viewpoint. ;-)

Comment: I know and agree with you. But I am a non professional frame of mind cursed with having to conform to the so called professional standards of this industry. Even if tables are correct for tabular data, the know it all clients who actually know nothing will crap all over themselves if they see a table in the source, no matter how you explain it to them. The demand of the industry moves the standard of code, not some place like w3c or whoever decides these things. In the end, the ones paying the bills are the ones that dictate the standard. And from a web firm, they always reject tables.

Comment: I think it is stupid, but whatever. From all I've had to do in this waste of talent industry, tables were only ever accepted in html newsletters and the very rare occasion of a data matrix, like reviewing which cities downloaded the most files from some site. Most layouts can be defined as tabular or at least loosely seen that way, so tables can make sense for almost any project. You just won't be favored for making a decision like that. The above example could be seen either way, but both columns looked like they would fit a standard size and would not suffer from a "modern" solution.

Comment: @ all above — while tables should not be used for general layout, the OP clearly shows 3 column tabular data, so a table is the appropriate paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

ya sure... you can use... you can even have your own custom attribute to carry your data which will never be shown to end user except in the source view.. sample is as follows:

```
<tr style="border-style:none" mydata="ROW ID 2">  and it can be accessed as ('tr').attr('mydata')
```

Comment: -1. Please don't encourage the use of non-standard attributes or DOM properties. In HTML 4 the *class* attribute can be used, in HTML5 *data-* attributes can be used also.

Comment: +1 I use non-standard attributes all the time and it's never caused any problem.

Comment: @jchavannes: The fact that something "never caused any problem" does not itself make it advisable, or best practice.  Most browsers *tolerate* invalid data, sometimes in a useful way, that does not mean you should deliberately give them it.

Comment: @jchavannes - different browsers treat non-standard attributes differently. If an attribute happens to have the same name as a DOM or host property in any browser (either now or in the future) that loads the page, the user will have issues. HTML5 has introduced a bunch of new attributes and deprecated a few as well. There are many alternatives to non-standard attributes, there is no good reason to use them given the known and potential future issues. e.g. [Problem with non-standard HTML attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462237/problem-with-non-standard-html-attributes)

Comment: You bring up a good point, there is a risk of choosing a name that corresponds with a DOM or host property in the future, and "data-" is the best way to prevent that.  However, it's been 10 years since HTML4, and HTML5 still hasn't been fully adopted, so I doubt they'll be adding "mydata" or "rowid" anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can use whichever attribute name you want

```
<tr style="border-style:none" rowid="1">
```

Then in jQuery you would access it by:

```
$('tr[rowid=1]');
```

or if you have a row and want to know it's id:

```
var rowid = $(this).attr('rowid');
```