# Custom HTML attributes and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am often needing to store little pieces of reference in a page element, most of the time a `<div>`. I couldn't find too much documentation on how valid it would be to create my own attributes. What do you suggest is the most valid way of doing this or can I even do this? If so, can I just use jQuery's attr() call to get the reference?

example : `<div class="sample" dataref="Sample Data Reference"></div>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-Standard Attributes on HTML Tags. Good Thing? Bad Thing? Your Thoughts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209428/non-standard-attributes-on-html-tags-good-thing-bad-thing-your-thoughts)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use HTML5 data attributes

See: http://api.jquery.com/data/

E.g.

```
<div class="sample" data-ref="some string" />
```

Then:

```
$('.sample').data('ref');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery data functionality. The data will not show in DOM, but you will able to set and access it fast. Documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Example:

```
// set value
$.data(element, key, value);

// get value
var value = $.data(element, key);
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel you can use any word other than "id" and "class" attributes to keep your data.