# JQuery : Is it bad practice to use a custom attribute in my html code?

Tags: jquery, html, custom-attributes

I've been adding custom attributes which I reference using JQuery, this works great. But is it good practice?

example:

```
<div class="monkeys" customattr="big Monkey"> </div>
```

thanks all

Comment: Nice to the point question with a nice example.  Bravo.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-Standard Attributes on HTML Tags. Good Thing? Bad Thing? Your Thoughts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209428/non-standard-attributes-on-html-tags-good-thing-bad-thing-your-thoughts)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Best practice is to use HTML5 `data-*` attributes:

```
<div class="monkeys" data-customattr="big Monkey"> </div>
```

This is standards-compliant HTML5, unlike arbitrary custom attributes.  It also makes sure that your custom attribute won't conflict with some future standard attribute.

In recent (1.5+) versions of jQuery, you can also use `$('.monkeys').data('customatrr')` to access the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. If you're not using HTML 5 (see @SLaks post) why not change your class to be descriptive?

```
<div class="big monkeys"> </div>
```

Comment: Now you're assigning two classes: _big_ and _monkeys_. Point taken, though, to use "bigMonkeys" or similar.

Comment: Yeah, but he probably already has styling for monkeys. And what if there are "small monkeys" or "baby monkeys". Taking a more OO approach is better unless he doesn't have that situation.  However, I'm guessing this question wouldn't come up if that were the case.

Comment: Fair enough. If that fits the situation, I'm all for it.