# Insert Listbox selected options to database NOT values

Tags: php, html, listbox

I'm implimenting a user registrations form for a college..There I need to calculate the fees and show it to the user and the same time need to insert to a database..

I have used a list box for like this

```
<select name="subject" id="select2"> ***(value=fees for the subject)
<option value="100">Arts</option>
<option value="150">English</option>
```

calculation is OK with the values wich are given(I used javascript calculation for that)
Now I want to insert the subject to database
ex:

```
INSERT INTO user(name, email, subject)
VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[subject]')");
```

I want to add the subject which selected to be add to database subject field as English not the fees.

I hope you can understand what I'm telling.Please Help

Thank You

Comment: How do you populate your `select`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should use the labels as values like:

```
<select name="subject">
<option value="Arts">Arts</option>
<option value="English">English</option>
```

If for any reason you want to post both label and fee you can use hidden variables and JavaScript like:

```
<select name="subject_fee" id="subject_fee" onchange="populate_subject_name();">
<option value="100">Arts</option>
<option value="150">English</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="subject_name" id="subject_name" value="">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function populate_subject_name() {
        var f = document.getElementById("subject_fee");
        var n = document.getElementById("subject_name");
        n.value = f.options[f.selectedIndex].text;
    }
</script>
```

By the way I'd still recommend the first approach. There are other ways to calculate the fee -- just improvise. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432174/how-to-store-arbitrary-data-for-some-html-tags) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209428/non-standard-attributes-on-html-tags-good-thing-bad-thing-your-thoughts) for one possibility.

Answer (score 0):

This would require the server-side knowing the text of the `SELECT` element, as only the selected value is posted back.

It's possible in ASP.NET, as the `SELECT` element is know server-side. However I'm not sure if this in the case in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

In php, when you populate your list, keep in a map the value=>label mapping and get back the right value like :

```
$arr = array(100 => "Arts", 150 => "English");
echo $arr[$_POST[subject]]; //if $_POST[subject]==100, return "Arts"
```

Otherwise, in javascript, you can get it with

```
var index=document.getElementById("select2").selectedIndex;
document.getElementById("select2").options[index].text;
```

Then you can store it in an hidden input text...

**Warning :**
Don't insert directly the values in the sql request !
Be carful with [injection SQL](http://sqlzoo.net/hack/)

Hope this help you...

Comment: Thanx Jean for your reply I feel that it my help me.Can you show me a example how to map a one value,because I haven't a good knowledge of mapping?? and thanks for your advice too

Comment: @nisal I add you an example of the array in php.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add handle `onsubmit` event of form and a hidden field to preserve the selected `text` of list item.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitIt()
 {
  var list=document.getElementById("select2");
  var item=list.item(list.selectedIndex);
  document.getElementById("subjectTest").value=item.text;
  return true;
}
</script>

<form method="post" action="your_page.php" onsubmit="return submitIt()">
   <input type="hidden" id="subjectTest" name="subjectText" />
   <select name="subject" id="select2"> ***(value=fees for the subject)
    <option value="100">Arts</option>
    <option value="150">English</option>
   <input type="submit" name="cmd" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```