# html5 data attributes backwards compatibility

Tags: html, backwards-compatibility

I've been reading up on custom data attributes for html webpages ([one example of the numerous ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209428/non-standard-attributes-on-html-tags-good-thing-bad-thing-your-thoughts)). From what I can tell going forward this is likely the best solution.

```
<div data-my_attrib="stackoverflow"></div>
```

My question pertains to backwards compatibility.

Supposedly the html standard specifies that unknown attributes should be ignored (I've read this comment multiple times, haven't actually read the standard myself :P), but are there any known browsers (including past versions, both mobile and PC-based) which might have problems with the new custom attribute specification? If so, which ones?

Additionally, are there any known possible issues where `data-something` might already be defined for old browsers (`something` is an arbitrary placeholder)? The focus is on core browser functionality (including standard addons shipped with the browser), ignore website scripts/libraries like JQuery and the likes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unknown attributes are ignored in that they don't do anything, but they are still available for `getAttribute` to retrieve.

I'm fairly sure it's safe to assume that `data-*` is not used for anything else - otherwise they would have chosen a different identifying keyword that didn't conflict with something else.

Answer (score 3):

There are no known issues with backwards compatibility for `data-*` attributes, certainly not with any browser you are actually likely to run into.

The whole don't-break-old-browsers thing is kind of one of the guiding principles of HTML5.