# Selecting Custom html attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I have this working, but I am wondering is this normal practice.

```
<button vacation="2" type="button" class="delete" id="vc-2"><i class="icon-static"></i></button>
```

I need custom attributes. I made custom html attribute called vacation. I am accessing it via event, something like this:

```
var vacation = parseInt(e.currentTarget.attributes[0].value); //Zero, since this is the first attribute.
```

This works, but I am interested is this the best practice? I would like to avoid using HTML5 data- attribute if possible.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid the mechanism put into HTML for exactly this sort of extension and use invalid markup instead? (Hint: Invalid HTML is not best practice).

Comment: This is exactly why the HTML5 data-* attribute exists.... why not use it?

Comment: If you're trying to avoid HTML5 for compatibility reasons, what about using just inner text or a class or some other such built-in mechanism?

Comment: I would use a class to denote custom attributes. Or within a form, using a hidden field. If you really want to do this for pre-HTML5 valid markup, please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735230/can-i-add-custom-attribute-to-html-tag

Comment: Could you specify the technical reason you try to avoid the HTML5 standard? While we're talking about 'best practice', it implies 'follow the standard'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-Standard Attributes on HTML Tags. Good Thing? Bad Thing? Your Thoughts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209428/non-standard-attributes-on-html-tags-good-thing-bad-thing-your-thoughts)

Answer (score 2):

Without using HTML5 data-* attributes, you could do the following...

**Markup**

```
<input type="hidden" value="2" id="vc-2-vacation" />
<button type="button" class="delete" id="vc-2"><i class="icon-static"></i></button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
 var vacation = ($(this).id + "-vacation").val();
}
```

**Update:** At first I gave the answer to use data-* attributes in HTML5. After being downvoted for providing the right answer but not exactly what the OP was asking I changed my answer to the less than ideal method above, which while works I would never use myself...

Below, you'll find the "best practices" answer which would be to use the data-* attribute of HTML5.

## Ideal Solution

**Markup**

```
<button data-vacation="2" class="delete" id="vc-2"><i class="icon-static"></i></button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".delete").on("click", function() { 
  var vacation = $(this).data("vacation");
});
```

Comment: Dear downvoters - I changed my answer to fit OPs question - even though using HTML5 data-* attribute is the best solution

Comment: +1 (I wasn't a downvoter) - I was downvoted for suggesting the same. I agree with you, there's absolutely no reason to avoid the `data-*` - it's valid and compatible with every browser.

Comment: I wasn't a downvoter. I wasn't an upvoter though either. Here's why. The answer you provided worked and fit the awkard no `data-` attributes guideline laid out by the OP. Therefore, I do not think it should be downvoted. However, that being said, the OP also asked about "best practices". The best practice would be to use the `data-` attributes as that as what they are designed to do (and what @Joe laid out in a previous deleted answer). This is a "work around" and therefore not the best practice.

Comment: @War10ck - I completely agree. Both me and Andy posted answers suggesting this but were heavily downvoted. Some users thought that `data-*` should be avoided just because the OP said so despite it being the correct approach.

Comment: @Andy Apologies, but I was a downvoter caught in the following trap, a mistake I won't make again. Upvoted your comment and spreading the word: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23701/why-cant-i-change-my-vote-if-the-post-has-been-edited-during-the-initial-5mn-gr

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. @War10ck I've edited my answer to explicitly answer the OP while providing the "Best Practices" solution of using HTML5 data-* attributes.

Comment: @AndyBrudtkuhl I hadn't casted a vote yet, but now I have. +1 solid solution buddy. My apologies if I seemed a little difficult to please. That wasn't my intention. I was just hoping for a thorough solution that details what the OP could do and what the OP should do. This accomplishes both. Well said. +1

Answer (score 0):

it's considered bad markup. Try to avoid it. If necessary use a hidden field and assign to the value attribute. Why are you against the HTML5 data attribute? That's what it was made for.

**EDIT**
To handle events you will need to use a click handler.

Your markup will look something like this:

```
<button type="button" class="delete" id="vc-2" data-vacation="2"> </button>
```

And your js/jquery will look like:

```
var button = $('#vc-2');
button.click(function(){ alert(button.data('vacation')); }); //click handler
```

Comment: If I wanted to use html5 data attribute, then how do I access it via event?

I have function that accepts e. So, e.currentTarget...... what do I put there?

Comment: @Emilly An event has to have a handler. Therefore, inside the `event` function you can use `$(this)` to get the current element and either `.attr(attributename)` or the more appropriate `.data(attributename)`...

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to avoid HTML5, then the best practice would be to use a class:

```
<button type="button" class="delete vacation-2" id="vc-2"><i class="icon-static"></i>  </button>
```

You can get the value using Regex:

```
 $('button').on('click', function(){
       var classList = $(this).attr('class');
       var patt = /vacation-([0-9]{1,})/;
       var vacation = classList.replace(patt, function(a,b){
                          return b;
                      });
       $(this).html(vacation);
 });
```

**[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ExceptionLimeCat/2Anhy/)**

Comment: Like _Andy's_ answer below, I won't downvote you because your solution works. That being said, I disagree with using classes for this. The OP should come to grips with the fact that the `data-` attributes were designed for this and are therefore best practice, pure and simple. No amount of "work arounds" will qualify as best practice.

Comment: I agree `data-` attribute is the best route to go but I have to assume there is some reason why they aren't able to use HTML5 features.

Comment: @ExceptionLimeCat Agreed which is why I won't downvote. It's a perfect legitimate answer. IMO the OP is being unreasonable with the guidelines and hasn't stipulated a reason for them.